# a:hover affects text hyperlinks, but not img hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

My html file has something like

```
<a href="foo.html">
  <img width="64" src="foo.svg" alt="foo"/>
</a>
```

and my css file has

```
body
{
    background: #FFF;
}
a:hover
{
    background: #ABB;
}
img
{
    background: #FFF;
}
```

This works fine for text hyperlinks. When hovering over a text hyperlink, the background color changes from FFF to ABB.

But in this case the img is also a hyperlink, and because it's svg, its background shows. How do I make the background of an img change while hovering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this syntax `a:hover img { }`

```
a:hover,
a:hover img
{
    background: #ABB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already setting a background for the image with this rule:

```
img
{
    background: #FFF;
}
```

If you want *that* background to change of the hover of the anchor, you have to make a rule for that.

```
a:hover img
{
    background: #F00;
}
```

Otherwise you need to make sure the image's (html) background is transparent so you're only displaying the background of the anchor.

If you're trying to embed svg into the page and use CSS for certain elements in THAT, that's a completely different thing.